# Screen shows a weird rectangle

Tags: graphics, visual-artifacts

Why is my netbook showing ugly rectangles?

[image: ugly rectangle 1]

[image: ugly rectangle 2]

Comment: do you have checked any additional video-drivers for your netbook? It might be just that itchy point.

Answer (score 1):

First try going to **System Settings > Software and Updates > Additional Drivers** and choosing another option.

If it didn't work, then follow the steps below:

Install CCSM:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

[image: CompizConfig]

In CCSM go to **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** and select **No Blur** option for **Dash Blur**.

[image: Ubuntu Unity Plugin]

Problem solved.